# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/techy9CustomerService/j_spring_security_check] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring-security

While logging error message dispalyed:
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/techy9CustomerService/j_spring_security_check] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Login Form :

```
    <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check"  data-has-location="true" class="lead-sheet-form"  accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">

<label class="lead-sheet-name-first" align="center" style="margin-top:50px ">
<input style="width:350px" id="lead-sheet-name-first" name="username" required placeholder="user id">
</label>
<label class="lead-sheet-name-first" align="center">
<input type="password" style=" width:350px" id="lead-sheet-name-first" name="password" required placeholder="password" >
</label>
<p align="center">
<button id="loginButton" class="button" style="background-color: rgb(0, 126, 229);border-color: rgb(0, 126, 229)" >Sign in</button>
</p>
<a class="" href="#" style="padding-left: 40px"><font color="#2895F1" size="2px">Forgot your password?</font></a>
</form:form>
```

spring-secuirty.xml:

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/users/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />



        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <form-login login-page="/home" authentication-failure-url="/home"
             default-target-url="/home" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/home" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="loginService" />
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already published the SpringSecurityFilterChain in web.xml?

You must have something like that in web.xml. Otherwise include it:

```
  <!--  Spring security filter chain -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I already published the above code

Comment: is there any thing to change in pom

Comment: its fixed; I added login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"